# Assigning to dataframe column based on dict value

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe df:

```
    Address City    State   Zip Code    Query Result
0   55 W Waterloo Rd    Akron   OH  44319   {'field1': 'street_number', 'longname1': '55', 'field2': 'route', 'longname2': 'West Waterloo Road'}
1   1120 Hwy 20 Correctionville IA  51016   {'field1': 'street_number', 'longname1': '1120', 'field2': 'route', 'longname2': 'U.S. 20'}
2   Hwy 12 and Bonito Dr    Fort Defiance   AZ  86504   {'field1': 'route', 'longname1': 'Indian Route 7', 'field2': 'locality', 'longname2': 'Fort Defiance'}
3   2661 County Hwy I   Chippewa Falls  WI  54729   {'field1': 'street_number', 'longname1': '2661', 'field2': 'route', 'longname2': 'County Highway I'}
4   301 US Rt 1 Ste A   Scarborough ME  4074    {'field1': 'subpremise', 'longname1': 'a', 'field2': 'street_number', 'longname2': '301'}
5   500 W Broadway St Ste 5 Missoula    MT  59807   {'field1': 'subpremise', 'longname1': '5', 'field2': 'street_number', 'longname2': '500'}
```

I would like to populate column df['street_number'] using the dict in df['Query Result'] such that:

```
    Address City    State   Zip Code    Query Result    street_number
0   55 W Waterloo Rd    Akron   OH  44319   {'field1': 'street_number', 'longname1': '55', 'field2': 'route', 'longname2': 'West Waterloo Road'}    55
1   1120 Hwy 20 Correctionville IA  51016   {'field1': 'street_number', 'longname1': '1120', 'field2': 'route', 'longname2': 'U.S. 20'} 1120
2   Hwy 12 and Bonito Dr    Fort Defiance   AZ  86504   {'field1': 'route', 'longname1': 'Indian Route 7', 'field2': 'locality', 'longname2': 'Fort Defiance'}  
3   2661 County Hwy I   Chippewa Falls  WI  54729   {'field1': 'street_number', 'longname1': '2661', 'field2': 'route', 'longname2': 'County Highway I'}    2661
4   301 US Rt 1 Ste A   Scarborough ME  4074    {'field1': 'subpremise', 'longname1': 'a', 'field2': 'street_number', 'longname2': '301'}   301
5   500 W Broadway St Ste 5 Missoula    MT  59807   {'field1': 'subpremise', 'longname1': '5', 'field2': 'street_number', 'longname2': '500'}   500
```

Can someone help me undertstand how to do this? Please let me know if I need to make my example clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, it seemed as if the street number was stored in the `"longname1"` field. If that were the case, and your `"Query Result"` column were stored as a `dict`, you can extract the street number easily `apply`:

```
df['street_number'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Query Result'].get('longname1'), axis=1)
```

Which prints:

```
    street_number                  Address             City State  Zip Code
0              55         55 W Waterloo Rd            Akron    OH     44319
1            1120              1120 Hwy 20  Correctionville    IA     51016
2  Indian Route 7     Hwy 12 and Bonito Dr    Fort Defiance    AZ     86504
3            2661        2661 County Hwy I   Chippewa Falls    WI     54729
4               a        301 US Rt 1 Ste A      Scarborough    ME      4074
5               5  500 W Broadway St Ste 5         Missoula    MT     59807
```

However this produces the wrong output - `"Indian Route 7"` and `"a"` don't look like street numbers. Therefore it the assumption that `"longname1"` is the key is flawed.

Taking a second look at the input, it seems that we need to find the key for the street number dynamically. Here is a quick and dirty approach.

Search for all of the keys in `"Query Result"` that start with the word `"field"`. Then for those, find the one whose corresponding value is `"street_number"`. Use the number at the end of the key as the `index`, and find the appropriate `"longname"` value:

```
def get_street_number(qr):
    fields = [k for k in qr if k.startswith('field')]
    street_number = [f for f in fields if qr[f] == 'street_number']
    try:
        # kind of a hacky way to get the number (index)
        index = street_number[0].split('field')[1]
        return qr['longname'+index]
    except:
        return None

df['street_number'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_street_number(x['Query Result']), axis=1)
```

(There are many ways to do this better, but it should work for your needs.)

The output from your sample data:

```
>>> print(df[['street_number', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code']])
  street_number                  Address             City State  Zip Code
0            55         55 W Waterloo Rd            Akron    OH     44319
1          1120              1120 Hwy 20  Correctionville    IA     51016
2          None     Hwy 12 and Bonito Dr    Fort Defiance    AZ     86504
3          2661        2661 County Hwy I   Chippewa Falls    WI     54729
4           301        301 US Rt 1 Ste A      Scarborough    ME      4074
5           500  500 W Broadway St Ste 5         Missoula    MT     59807
```

Which matches with the example you provided.

**Update**:

If your `Query Result` is stored as a `string`, you can convert it to a `dict` using `json.loads()`:

```
import json
df['Query Result'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: json.loads(x['Query Result'].replace("'", '"')), axis=1
)
```

Or if  you're reading from a file, you can use the `converters` option in `read_csv()` to do the conversion on read:

```
filename = 'path/to/file'
df = pd.read_csv(
    filename,
    converters={'Query Result': lambda x: json.loads(x.replace("'", '"'))}
)
```

Comment: This is gorgeous, thank you so much. One matter of curiosity: why the lambda? I seem to be getting the same output if I run df['street_number'] = df['Query Result'].apply(get_street_number)

Comment: Your way is the same. I used `lambda` because I called `apply` on the whole dataframe, and I wanted to pass just the one `dict` column to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

My example DataFrame (I omitted some stuff from your example for brevity):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code', 'Query Result'])
df.loc[0] = ['55 W Waterloo Rd', 'Akron', 'OH', 44319, {'field1': 'street_number', 'longname1': '55'}]
df

    Address     City    State   Zip Code    Query Result
0   55 W Waterloo Rd    Akron   OH  44319   {'longname1': '55', 'field1': 'street_number'}
```

The trick seemed to be accessing the dict, because it is nested in an array:

```
df['Street Number'] = df['Query Result'].values[0]['longname1']
df


    Address     City    State   Zip Code    Query Result    Street Number
0   55 W Waterloo Rd    Akron   OH  44319   {'longname1': '55', 'field1': 'street_number'}  55
```